# grep only files generated in a particular hour

Tags: performance, shell, time, scripting, grep

I am trying to grep some pattern in a file set under a folder like below
Where on the output I have to perform remaining operation.
The output main.log is coming so huge almost 50k lines ,as the files starting with server02.log are almost 30 to 40 in number . The script based on this output is taking forever to complete.
Is there a way that I can only take files name starting with server02.log. and generated between time
20:00:00 and 21:00:00

```
ls -lrth server02.log.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.9M Apr 15 20:20 server02.log.2020
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.7M Apr 15 20:30 server02.log.2030
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.6M Apr 15 20:41 server02.log.2041
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.9M Apr 15 20:50 server02.log.2050
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2.1M Apr 15 21:00 server02.log.2100
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.4M Apr 15 21:10 server02.log.2110
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.9M Apr 15 21:20 server02.log.2120
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  656K Apr 15 21:29 server02.log.2129
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  4.6M Apr 15 21:40 server02.log.2140
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.9M Apr 15 21:50 server02.log.2150
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.7M Apr 15 21:59 server02.log.2159
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  724K Apr 15 22:09 server02.log.2209
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.3M Apr 15 22:20 server02.log.2220
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.1M Apr 15 22:29 server02.log.2229
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.7M Apr 15 22:41 server02.log.2241
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.5M Apr 15 22:49 server02.log.2249
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2.4M Apr 15 23:01 server02.log.2301
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1.4M Apr 15 23:10 server02.log.2310
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  585K Apr 15 23:19 server02.log.2319
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  858K Apr 15 23:30 server02.log.2330
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  892K Apr 15 23:40 server02.log.2340
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  698K Apr 15 23:49 server02.log.2349

grep -E "###Update |###Initiate |###Re-Initiate " server02.log.* >> main.log
```

from the comments I made the change to my code as below

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="."
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
log_dir="logs/$d"
PREFIX="$log_dir/srv_02.log"
#PREFIX="srv_02.log"
echo "prefix value is $PREFIX"

START_HOUR="06"

for F in "$( find "$DIR" -name "${PREFIX}*" -printf '%Tc %p\n' | grep "\ ${START_HOUR}:" )"; do
  echo "F value is $F"
grep -E "###Update |###Initiate |###Re-Initiate" "$F" >> main.log

done

error:

prefix value is logs/2021-04-16/srv_02.log

find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `logs/2021-04-16/srv_02.log*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `logs/2021-04-16/osbpd_srv_02.log*''.
F value is
grep: : No such file or directory
```

Comment: With GNU `find` and coreutils `stat` you could do: `find "$log_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'srv_02.log.*' -exec sh -c 'stat -c %y {} | grep -q \ 20:' \; -print | xargs grep -E '###...' >>main.log` - assuming time interval is [20:00:00,21:00:00) and not [20:00:00,21:00:00]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution looks for files in the given directory, created during the specified hour with names matching the given prefix.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
DIR="logs/$d/$log_dir"
PREFIX="srv_02.log"
#PREFIX=server02.log
echo "prefix value is $PREFIX"

START_HOUR="06"
for F in "$( find "$DIR" -name "${PREFIX}*" -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | grep "\ ${START_HOUR}:" )"; do
  echo "$F"
  # grep -E "###Update |###Initiate |###Re-Initiate Assignment Milestone|###Complete Assignment Milestone|###Cancel Assignment Milestone|###Suspend Assignment Milestone|###Resume Assignment Milestone" "$F" >> main.log
done
```

Comment: don't you need to strip out the date from `$F` ?

Comment: That was not part of the spec. You might assume that days are significant, but there are viable scenarios where that would not be the case. Reading in extra complexity into a spec can be a significant source of problems.

Comment: Thank you .. I tried this .. some how the value of $F is coming as null

Comment: `null`? I do not think so. Bash does not support the concept of `null`. An empty string, perhaps, but that seems unlikely. Please append to your question exactly what your program looks like now, and the exact output or error.

Comment: Thank you .. I tried this .. some how the value of $F is coming as null

prefix value is logs/2021-04-16/server02.log
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  means that '-name `logs/2021-04-16/server02.log.log*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time .  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `logs/2021-04-16/server02.log.log*''.
F value is
grep: : No such file or directory

its issue with name  seems

Comment: That is really hard to read. **Please append to your question exactly what your program looks like now, and the exact output or error. **

Comment: Hi Mike
done .. I have edited question with code and respective error it had thrown when executed

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I adjusted my answer. BTW, I see you changed the PREFIX. I did too.

Comment: now the value of F is coming. But its appending some extra things

F value is Fri 16 Apr 2021 06:30:10 AM EDT logs/2021-04-16/srv_02.log.0630
;
it should be 
F value is logs/2021-04-16/srv_02.log.0630

Comment: The problem was the `-printf`. I hope I fixed it. Hard to know for sure without the files.

Comment: This is agin printingemprty $F .The previous one partially solved my issue. .
Will go with it .
Thank you Mike for the help

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote it. I think I earned it!

Comment: @MikeSlinn the code I commented on set `$F` to `%Tc %p` but should have stripped `%Tc ` before using it. The current code does not even include the filename (`%TY-%Tm-%Td`). Also, you are incorrectly quoting the `$()`